# Magento 2 locale files not loaded after static deloy

Tags: magento2

I am getting so frustrated by Magento 2 static deploys and it's not working for me. It did but not anymore. I have the following situation

- Store 1 - **english**
- Store 2 - **Dutch (nl_NL)**
- Store 3 - **German (de_DE)**

The NL and DE languages are installed through the mageplaze composer modules. 
Magento just doesn't show the correct translations

When I deploy `nl_NL`

magerun2 `setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_NL`

it shows

Deploy using quick strategy

```
frontend/Magento/blank/nl_NL            2593/2593           ============================ 100% %  6 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/nl_NL         2374/2374           ============================ 100% %  6 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/nl_NL             2609/2609           ============================ 100% %  6 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto/nl_NL          2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  7 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/nl_NL      2783/2783           ============================ 100% %  7 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/nl_NL    2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  7 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_b2b/nl_NL      2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  7 secs
```

I also see the locale folders in the pub static folders

I also did the following

**- rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/* var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/* var/composer_home
 - Disabled all cache
 - Through commandline cleared varnish
 - Disabled varnish
 - Reconfigured varnish**

when I look at my frontpage code I see this

```
<head >
    <script>
var BASE_URL = 'http://....com/nl/';
var require = {
    "baseUrl": "http://......com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB"
```

I have no idea anymore :(

also tried production mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
Enabling maintenance mode
Config "dev/debug/debug_logging = 0" has been saved.
Starting compilation
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 74.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 74.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 7 secs 224.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 7 secs 224.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 7 secs 224.0 MiB
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 7 secs 224.0 MiB
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 12 secs 246.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 12 secs 246.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 23 secs 300.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 23 secs 300.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 31 secs 404.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 31 secs 404.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 35 secs 410.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
Compilation complete
Starting deployment of static content

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/nl_NL            2593/2593           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/nl_NL         2374/2374           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/de_DE            2593/2593           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB            2593/2593           ============================ 100% %  12 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2593/2593           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/de_DE         2374/2374           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB         2374/2374           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2374/2374           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/nl_NL             2609/2609           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto/nl_NL          2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE             2609/2609           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB             2609/2609           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2609/2609           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto/de_DE          2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  16 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB          2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US          2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/nl_NL      2783/2783           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/nl_NL    2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  17 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_b2b/nl_NL      2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/de_DE      2783/2783           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/en_GB      2783/2783           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/en_US      2783/2783           ============================ 100% %  16 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/de_DE    2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  15 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB    2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US    2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_b2b/de_DE      2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  17 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_b2b/en_GB      2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  14 secs
frontend/Smartwave/porto_b2b/en_US      2780/2780           ============================ 100% %  14 secs

Execution time: 430.81158995628
Deployment of static content complete
Disabling maintenance mode
Enabled production mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Issue was the nginx multistore settings